# Run Cutechess-cli on heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, stockfish

Is it possible to run cutechess tournament on heroku. I can run normally run fishtest on heroku btw.

I tried it with docker but its giving me qt5 error. I tried to install cutechess from sources inside docker, copied cutechess-cli files to repo it runs but givin me uci or xboard error.

Comment: Please read [ask]. "Is it possible to do X?" isn't a very good question. Please [edit] your question and show us _how_ you tried to do this with Docker along with the exact error messages you got. Similarly for your "install from sources" attempt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.